# Is this a form of stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: optimization, stochastic

I want to minimize the following with respect to parameters $B$.

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{K} f(A_{k}, B)$$

where $A_k$ are $K$ different data-sets and $B$ is a matrix of parameters.

Can I do this by a gradient descent where:

1. randomly pick *one* matrix $A_{i}$ among $K$ matrices.
2. perform a gradient step that minimizes $f(A_{i}, B)$
3. repeat steps 1 and 2 until convergence.

The function $f$ is the logarithm of a linear function.

After searching online, this looks like a stochastic gradient descent.
Is this really an SGD?

Comment: Yes this is SGD.